# Function only returns last value to list

Tags: python

So, I produced the following code, where a function must be used.
Also, the temperatures in Fahrenheit are given in a list.
The goal is to convert the temperatures to Celcius and put them in a list.
Problem is that the list is only filled with the last value...
How can I edit my code so that it prints:

```
[0.0, 37.77777777777778] ##desired output.
```

My code:

```
def fahrenheit_to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
fahrenheit = [32, 100]
for t in fahrenheit:
    celcius = [fahrenheit_to_celsius(t)]
print(celcius)

## out = [37.77777777777778]
```

Comment: you are assigning celcius to a list only containing one value. you can do `celcius.append(fahrenheit_to_celsius(t))` to add to the list, also initialise the celcius list before hand by celcius = list() or celcius = []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append inside the loop, currently you are overwriting:

```
def fahrenheit_to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9


fahrenheit = [32, 100]
celsius = []
for t in fahrenheit:
    celsius.append(fahrenheit_to_celsius(t))
print(celsius)
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for operations on list. As an alternative consider a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
fahrenheit = [32, 100]
celsius = [fahrenheit_to_celsius(t) for t in fahrenheit]
print(celsius)
```

**Output**

```
[0.0, 37.77777777777778]
```

Answer (score 1):

list object `celcius` (having only 1 element)is getting overwriting the previous value. as you are not appending the data in the list but overwriting the data. all you need to do is append the data in list object `celcius`

```
 def fahrenheit_to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
fahrenheit = [32, 100]
celcius = [] # or use list comprehension as celcius = [fahrenheit_to_celsius(i) for i in fahrenheit]
for t in fahrenheit:
    celcius.append(fahrenheit_to_celsius(t))
print(celcius)
# [0.0, 37.77777777777778] ##desired output.
```